# XPath result as array of named keys in PHP

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Dom parsing with PHP is a pain. Certainly if you take a look at how easy it is with JavaScript.

This is how I get all attributes from each input element:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<form><input type="text" required /><input type="password" name="password" required /></form>');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$result = $xpath->query('//input/@*');

foreach($result as $key=>$value) {

    echo $key . ': ' . $value->nodeValue . '<br />';
}
```

How can you get named keys instead of numbered keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dom parsing in PHP is the same as JS since they use the same interface (the standard [Document Object Model](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR))...  The only difference is that in JS it's easy to introspect the individual elements (whereas in PHP it's kept below the API since it's implemented in C).

Now, for your exact question, the return type of `$value` is [DomAttr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domattr.php).  So this should do it for you:

```
echo $value->name . ': ' . $value->value . '<br />';
```

**Edit:** Regarding your comment.  Do it this way:

```
$result = $xpath->query('//input');

$inputs = array();
foreach($result as $element) {
    $current = array();
    foreach ($element->attributes as $attribute) {
        $current[$attribute->name] = $attribute->value;
    }
    $inputs[] = $current;
}
```

Comment: Seems to work! Do you also know how to separate the inputs so you basically get two different object instead of one? Example: $inputs=>array(0=>array(type=>'text',required=>),1=>array(type='password',required=>))

Comment: Thank you very much for your second answer. Works perfect now. I am building a form processor (using PHP output buffering too). It's a hell to build this perfectly but it will enable me to convert a simple HTML form into a working form in seconds instead of hours :)